# ProgressBar in AsyncTask - showing after onPostExecute method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I retreive data from server by means of external class which contains AsyncTask:

```
public class GetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    private Context context;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    public GetTask(Context cxt) {
        context = cxt;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setTitle("Load...");
        dialog.setMessage("Data...");
        dialog.show();

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... url) {

        // code for retreive data
        return jArray;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject object) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(object);
    }
}
```

I call this task from my activity:

```
Tasks task = new Tasks();
JSONObject json = task.new GetTask(this).execute(ServerURL).get();
```

My data retrieved successfully but ProgressDialog show after super.onPostExecute(object); method, why?

P.S. dialog show after:

```
    // Make sure the identity of this thread is that of the local process,
    // and keep track of what that identity token actually is.
    Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
    final long ident = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
```

on internal Looper.class

Sorry my english is bad. ))

Comment: did you cancell your task?

Comment: you mean - dialog.setCancelable(true); ?

Comment: no I mean task.cancel(true). Are you sure the onPostExecute is being called?

Comment: I debug my app, yes onPostExecute is being called, after onPostExecute debugger swith to Looper.class and show dialog after code `Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
 final long ident = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();`

Comment: Hi, problem resolve after delete .get(); method from calling task procedure.. Plese help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, need use callback and not use .get() method. I call my task:

```
callTask(linkODeatails, obj);
```

callTask:

```
void callTask(String link, String object){
    task.new GetTask(this).execute(link + object);

}
```

I create interface:

```
public interface AsyncTaskCompleteListener {
public void onTaskComplete(JSONObject result);
```

}

And added on my task:

```
        private Activity activity;
    private AsyncTaskCompleteListener callback;

    public GetTask(Activity act){
        this.activity = act;
        this.callback = (AsyncTaskCompleteListener)act;
    }
```

them called:

```
callback.onTaskComplete(result, object);
```